# Alertdialog without contentview

Tags: android

Is there any way to call an alertbox in a MainActivity without setting a layout for it. I have a MainActivity and an AlertboxActivity, but i want no xml layout for the AlertboxActivity. I just want to call and execute the code in de main.xml

Comment: You just want to show a simple AlertDialog, is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment above stated. Are you just wanting to make a dialog box? 
You can create views quite easily using the parent view. For instance! Your main_activity_layout.xml 
contains a root "container" layout. IE Relative layout etc.. Give the root layout a ID and then initiate it in your main activity. `IE RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.Id.MYID);`
next to add a view to it. 
`myLayout.addView(new LinearLayout()`).. Etc etc...

```
  AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setMessage("MY ALERT MESSAGE")
            .setTitle("MY TITLE")
            .setNegativeButton("NO BUTTON", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("YES BUTTON", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .create();
    //and to show
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: yes, but the java code of the alertbox must be in another activity not in the MainActivity. the view of the alertbox must be in the main.xml though

Comment: Hmm. Are both activities running at the same time? If only the one activity is running what good would it do to show a alert on another activity? If they are both running use a handler with a looper from your first activity..

Comment: i made an empty.xml and it shows the alertbox just the way i want to.